# Line alignment with \par

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

I was writing a document in LaTeX and found out that I am not able to properly align the text when I use `\\` or `\newline`

Here is the code.

```
 \par{ {\bfseries{\today}} \vspace{1\baselineskip}

 Name \\
 Address \\
 Contact Details
       }
```

The output is like

[image]

What I want is that Address and Contact Details appear just below Name.

Comment: Using `\noindent` at the start of a paragraph prevents paragraph indentation. You can also use the `tabular` envirement to align things.

Comment: `tabular` does work but I wanted to make things more simpler, silly me should have tried `\noindent` . Thanks for the tip, worked fine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add a `\par` at the end of each line which produces the first section below.  Note that each paragraph is indented. As Marc van Dongen commented, if you want things to be at the left margin, you need to add a `\noindent`, as shown in the second example:

[image]

However, for this kind of material is better to use a `tabular` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to show the margins of the page.
- `\bfseries` does not take a parameter, so the correct usage would have been `{\bfseries\today}`.
- You can use `\bigskip`, `\medskip`, `\smallskip` for vertical space adjustments, or add an optional space after in the tabular as `\\[2.0ex]`

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\textbf{\today} 
\vspace{1\baselineskip}

Name\par
Address\par
Contact Details

\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{\today} 
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\par\noindent Name
\par\noindent Address
\par\noindent Contact Details

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\textbf{\today} \\[2.0ex]
Name            & Shashwat \\
Address         & 123 Any Street \\
Contact Details & myemail@provider.com \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips for skipping lines :)

Will come handy . However I don't understand the function of `@` in `Latex` can you please clarify the use of `@{}` inside tabular arguments

Comment: @Shashwat: In a table like environment such as `tabular` there is a space that is inserted in between columns. The `@{}` in this MWE is used to suppress the inter column spacing.  So I put it _before_ the first column so that there is no space to the left of the first column -- hence it aligns with the margin. Try taking it out to see the effect.